# FFMPEG video combining and resizing issue

Tags: ffmpeg

I want a FFMPEG Template for Combing Videos. I have already develop a code of combining clips

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i C:\vids\ffmpeg\f.txt -c copy C:\vids\ffmpeg\test.mp4
```

but I want to resize it as HD (720p). I have searched alot but couldn't find the solution. Kindly help me.

Comment: Try to format a little your question, its hard to read. Make use of the formatting helpers while editing to use code block around commands.

Answer (score 0):

`-c copy` disables the decoding/encoding part of the pipeline, which makes it impossible to use video filters like scale.

In your case you need to specify output video codec parameters, and only copy the audio streams, while the video stream is decoded, scaled, and then encoded again.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i C:\vids\ffmpeg\f.txt -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -filter:v scale=1280:720  C:\vids\ffmpeg\test.mp4
```

Note that this example omits advanced x264 options which you can adjust as needed to obtain the desired quality.